# How to set custom headers in AWS ApiGatewy Method

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a rest service published (built as Lambda Function in Java) using Amazon Api Gateway.

I need to expose a custom header (at same level of Content-Type, Content-Length, Connection, etc.).

I have the value that I need to set up in the custom header in the Lambda Function output.

How can I create that header and set the value?

Comment: Just add  > headers: {"content-type": "text/html" ... etc } to response.

Comment: But how? In the lambda function output, I already have it. But what should I do in the Amazon API Gateway?